# Is there a command to see where a disk is mounted?

Tags: mount

Is there a simple command that takes a disk's device node as input, and tells me where (and whether) that disk is mounted? Is it possible to get the mount point by itself, so I can pass it to another command?

I'm working on a Debian Squeeze live system with a minimal install (I can install extra packages if need be).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

On Linux, you can now use the `findmnt` command from `util-linux` (since version 2.18):

```
$ findmnt -S /dev/VG_SC/home
TARGET SOURCE                 FSTYPE OPTIONS
/home  /dev/mapper/VG_SC-home ext4   rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered
```

Or `lsblk` (also from `util-linux`, since 2.19):

```
$ lsblk /dev/VG_SC/home
NAME       MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
VG_SC-home 254:2    0  200G  0 lvm  /home
```

That one is also useful to find all the file system mounted under a specific device (disk or partition...):

```
$ lsblk  /dev/sda2
NAME                    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda2                      8:2    0  59.5G  0 part
├─linux-debian64 (dm-1) 252:1    0    15G  0 lvm
└─linux-mint (dm-2)     252:2    0    15G  0 lvm  /
```

To get the mountpoint only:

```
$ findmnt -nr -o target -S /dev/storage/home
/home
$ lsblk -o MOUNTPOINT -nr /dev/storage/home
/home
```

Above `findmnt` does return with a failure exit status if the device is not mounted, not `lsblk`.

So:

```
if mountpoint=$(findmnt -nr -o target -S "$device"); then
  printf '"%s" is mounted on "%s"\n' "$device" "$mountpoint"
else
  printf '"%s" does not appear to be directly mounted\n' "$device"
fi
```

Comment: It's always good to learn something new

Answer (score 19):

Under Linux, you can get mount point information directly from the kernel in `/proc/mounts`. The `mount` program records similar information in `/etc/mtab`. The paths and options may be different, as `/etc/mtab` represents what `mount` passed to the kernel whereas `/proc/mounts` shows the data as seen inside the kernel. `/proc/mounts` is always up-to-date whereas `/etc/mtab` might not be if `/etc` was read-only at some point that wasn't expected by the boot scripts. The format is similar to [`/etc/fstab`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab).

In both files, the first whitespace-separated field contains the device path and the second field contains the mount point.

```
awk -v needle="$device_path" '$1==needle {print $2}' /proc/mounts
```

or if you don't have awk:

```
grep "^$device_path " /proc/mounts | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

There are a number of edge cases where you might not get what you expect. If the device was mounted via a different path in `/dev` that designates the same device, you won't notice it this way. In `/proc/mounts`, bind mounts are indistinguishable from the original. There may be more than one match if a mount point shadows another (this is unusual).

In `/proc/self` or `/proc/$pid`, there is a per-process `mounts` file that mimics the global file. The mount information may vary between processes, for example due to [`chroot`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot). There is an additional file called `mountinfo` that has a different format and includes more information, in particular the device major and minor numbers. From the [documentation](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt):

```
36 35 98:0 /mnt1 /mnt2 rw,noatime master:1 - ext3 /dev/root rw,errors=continue
(1)(2)(3)   (4)   (5)      (6)      (7)   (8) (9)   (10)         (11)

(1) mount ID:  unique identifier of the mount (may be reused after umount)
(2) parent ID:  ID of parent (or of self for the top of the mount tree)
(3) major:minor:  value of st_dev for files on filesystem
(4) root:  root of the mount within the filesystem
(5) mount point:  mount point relative to the process's root
(6) mount options:  per mount options
(7) optional fields:  zero or more fields of the form "tag[:value]"
(8) separator:  marks the end of the optional fields
(9) filesystem type:  name of filesystem of the form "type[.subtype]"
(10) mount source:  filesystem specific information or "none"
(11) super options:  per super block options
```

So if you're looking for a device by number, you can do it like this:

```
awk -v dev="$major:minor" '$3==dev {print $5}'
awk -v dev="$(stat -L -c %t:%T /dev/block/something)" '$3==dev {print $5}'
```

Comment: *"If the device was mounted via a different path in /dev that designates the same device, you won't notice it this way."* — That is actually the case: I have the `udisks` symlink (in /dev/disk/by-label/...). But I can resolve to a device node using `readlink -f`. I like the `/proc/mounts` idea, I think that might be a bit more reliable than `/etc/mtab`.

Comment: @detly Or you can use `mountinfo`. Call `stat` to get the device numbers (see my updated answer, I forgot to include the command earlier).

Comment: You may need `-d " "` option for `cut` in that `grep` command.

Comment: [There now are `findmnt` and `lsblk` dedicated commands that do the hard work (more robustly) for you](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/217412)

Answer (score 6):

The `mount` command with no arguments will list all currently mounted filesystems; you can `grep` that for the disk you want (or `grep` `/etc/mtab`, which is the file `mount` reads the information from):

```
$ grep /dev/sda /etc/mtab
/dev/sda3 /boot ext2 rw,noatime 0 0
```

Comment: That has a lot of extraneous text though. I need to be able to pass the mount point to other commands. (Sorry, I've clarified that in the Q.)

Comment: Ah, `grep ${NODE} /etc/mtab | cut -d ' ' -f 2` should do it.

Comment: Although `grep ^"${NODE}[[:space:]]\+" /etc/mtab | cut -d ' ' -f 2"` is much less fragile...

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You can see [Showing Only Interesting Mount Points/Filtering Non-Interesting Types](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/177014/52934) or [Listing Directories under `/` that are Not Under the Same Mountpoint](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/215636/52934) for some example usage, but there's also a brief rundown below. The command you are asking about is `findmnt` *(though `lsblk` might also serve)*:

```sh
lsblk -f /dev/sda[12]
```

---

```
NAME FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda1 vfat   ESP   F0B7-5DAE                            /esp
sda2 btrfs  sys   94749918-bde1-46e6-b77c-b66e0368ecdb /
```

Now, as you can see, `/dev/sda1` is mounted on `/esp`. I wonder if it is mounted elsewhere as well?

```sh
findmnt /dev/sda1
```

---

```
TARGET SOURCE                    FSTYPE OPTIONS
/esp   /dev/sda1                 vfat   rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/boot  /dev/sda1[/EFI/arch_root] vfat   rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
```

Aha. I see. A subfolder is also `--bind` mounted over boot. Ok...

```sh
sudo umount /boot /esp
findmnt /dev/sda1
```

Nothing. What the hell?

```sh
echo "$?"
```

---

```
1
```

Ohhh... Well, that's nice. Hmmm...

```sh
for d in 1 2
do    findmnt "/dev/sda$d" >/dev/null
      printf  "/dev/sda$d%.$((6>>!$?))s%s\n"\
              " isn't" " currently mounted."
done
```

---

```
/dev/sda1 isn't currently mounted.
/dev/sda2 is currently mounted.
```

Oh, yeah, that's really nice.

```sh
for d in /dev/sd*
do    findmnt -noSOURCE,TARGET "$d"
done
```

---

```
/dev/sda2[/arch_root] /
```

Now let's put sda1 back where it belongs and try that again...

```sh
sudo mount -a
for d in /dev/sd*
do    findmnt -noSOURCE,TARGET "$d"
done
```

---

```
/dev/sda1                 /esp
/dev/sda1[/EFI/arch_root] /boot
/dev/sda2[/arch_root] /
```

But where did I find this magical command?

> `man mount | sed -e:n -e'/findmnt/!d;N;/\n$/q;bn'`
>
> > For more robust and customizable output use [`findmnt`(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/findmnt),  especially in your scripts. Note that control characters in the mountpoint name are replaced with *`?`*.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a clean and simple way to detect whether or not a device node in `/dev` is mounted. This is what I can offer, though. It handles directly mounted devices (`/dev/sda1`) and devices mounted by UUID (`/dev/disk/by-uuid/aa4e7b08-6547-4b5a-85ad-094e9e1af74f`). It breaks if your device names contain whitespace.

```
deviceIsMounted()
{
    local DEVICE="$1"
    local MOUNT=$(
        (
            echo "$DEVICE"
            find /dev -type l -lname "*${DEVICE/*\/}" -exec readlink -f {} \; -print |
                xargs -n2 |
                awk -v device="$DEVICE" '$1 == device {print $2}'
        ) |
            xargs -n1 -i{} grep -F {} /proc/mounts
    )
    test -n "$MOUNT" && echo "$MOUNT"
}

deviceIsMounted /dev/sda1 && echo yes              # Mountpoint and status
deviceIsMounted /dev/md2 >/dev/null && echo yes    # Just status
```

The function writes the entry from `/proc/mounts` to *stdout* if found, also setting exit status to 0. Otherwise the exit status is 1.

Answer (score -1):

Just run the below command:

```
df -h
```