# How can I check mnt location?

Tags: filesystems

On RedHat I'm able to do this:

```
$ df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1             8256952   1820752   6352340  23% /
tmpfs                   305624         0    305624   0% /dev/shm
//10.128.41.24/linux-www
                     125826044 125826044         0 100% /mnt/inf1/linux-www
```

but on ubuntu not so:

```
$ df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             15481840   3958456  10736952  27% /
none                    296028       108    295920   1% /dev
none                    303244         0    303244   0% /dev/shm
none                    303244        64    303180   1% /var/run
none                    303244         0    303244   0% /var/lock

$ df /mnt/inf1/linux-www
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1             15481840   3958612  10736796  27% /

$ mount
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
none on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
none on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /var/run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
none on /var/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)

$ awk -v needle="$device_path" '$1==needle {print $2}' /proc/mounts
[nothing]

$ grep /dev/sda /etc/mtab
[nothing]

**OH! It's because it's a folder! Sneaky!**
```

`/mnt/inf1` exists on the ubuntu machine too. I'd like to know what it's pointing too, how do I go about doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `df /mnt/inf1/linux-www` to get the information about a specific filesystem. `df` can be told to ignore some filesystem types, check that you (or your system administrator) haven't aliased `df` to something like `df -l`. See also [Is there a command to see where a disk is mounted?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34718/is-there-a-command-to-see-where-a-disk-is-mounted)

Comment: Oh! I think I know why it wasn't showing up. Whoever set that server up didn't actually mount anything on this machine. They set it up as a folder! Sneaky! Thanks.