# Obtain device name and mount point if partition label is known

Tags: mount, freebsd, solaris, block-device, posix

How to obtain the partition device name and mount point when the file system
label is known?

There are several possibilities:

### Linux

#### File system label to device name

The device name can be obtained with `blkid`:

```
blkid -l -o device -t LABEL="$label" -c /dev/null
```

#### Device name to mount point

I tried obtaining the mount point with `blkid`, but I failed. Using the `-s`
switch all other fields can be queried when the label is provided:

```
blkid -l -t LABEL="$label" -o value -s LABEL      # yields label
blkid -l -t LABEL="$label" -o value -s TYPE       # yields partition type
blkid -l -t LABEL="$label" -o value -s UUID       # yields UUID
blkid -l -t LABEL="$label" -o value -s MOUNTPOINT # yields nothing
```

Obtaining the mount point is not supported apparently, though it is listed
when the `-o list` option is given, but not in an easy parseable way:

```
blkid -o list -c /dev/null <device>
```

The next attempt was to use `df -P`. Here's what I came up with, assuming the
device is stored in the variable `device`:

```
export device
mountpoint=$(df -P |
  awk --assign dev="$device" \
    '{if ($1==dev)             \
      {for (i=1; i<=NF-5; i++) \
        $i=$(i+5);             \
        NF-=5;                 \
        print                  \
      }                        \
    }')
```

This code works. However, given it's ugliness I'm not convinced that parsing
`df` is the preferred way.

### Other Unices

#### File system label to device name

`blkid` works beautifully on Linux, but it's not available on Solaris or
FreeBSD (at least one can't expect it to be installed). The same goes for
`findfs`.

How do I obtain the device name in a portable way on Linux, Solaris and
FreeBSD?

#### Device name to mount point

Happily `df -P` produces very similar output on all tested systems. The
problem is that my ugly `awk` script doesn't seem to be portable (tested with
Sun `awk`, `gawk` on Solaris and FreeBSDs `awk`). What's the preferred way?

### Related questions

[How to get the mount point of flash drive by using uuid?](https://serverfault.com/q/271895/102215)
Problem: Parsing `/proc/mounts` is not portable and troublesome even on Linux.
Parsing `mount` seems even worse. Perl is generally not available.

[Is there a command to see where a disk is mounted?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34718/12779)
Problem: Parses `/proc/mounts` with a buggy `awk` script. The solutions aren't portable.

### Summary

I'd like to obtain the device name and mount point when the file system label
is provided in a portable way (assuming a POSIX shell). The disk label might
contain white space or other non-ASCII characters which seems to complicate
things even more.

```
         Label-To-Device    Device-To-Mount-Point
         ---------------    ---------------------
Linux           ✓                    ✓ (ugly)
Solaris         .                    .
FreeBSD         .                    .
```

Comment: Unnecessary I think, udisks already did the job

Answer (score 1):

You can follow these steps to do it:

1. get `devname` using `blkid_dev_devname(...)`
2. get `prob` for this partition using `blkid_new_probe_from_filename(...)`
3. use `setmntent(...)`, `getmntent(...)`, & `endmntent(...)`, where  `mnt->mnt_fsname` equals to `devname` copy `mnt->mnt_dir` which is mount point!

#### See these references for further details

- http://linux.die.net/man/3/getmntent
- https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.21/libblkid-docs/api-index-full.html

#### mntent data structure

```
struct mntent {    
    char *mnt_fsname;   /* name of mounted file system */    
    char *mnt_dir;      /* file system path prefix */      
    ...
};
```