# Get label of Linux storage partition device file

Tags: linux, partition, block-device

Given the partition device file `/dev/sdh1`, I need to find out the label of this device.

`dmesg` doesn't mention its label while GParted reveals that it is called **H2N_SD**:

[image: gparted info about /dev/sdh]

I need to build a way to be able to run something similar to

```
$ partlabel /dev/sdh1
H2N_SD
```

*This question is nearly the opposite of [getting device name & mount point from label](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69028/obtain-device-name-and-mount-point-if-partition-label-is-known).*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `blkid`:

```
$ blkid -s LABEL -o value /dev/sdh1
H2N_SD
```

Comment: Or `lsblk -no label /dev/sdh1`...