# How to get mount point of filesystem containing given file

Tags: shell, filesystems, mount

I am looking for a quick way to find the mount point of the file system containing a given FILE.  Is there anything simpler or more direct than my solution below?

```
df -h FILE |tail -1 | awk -F% '{print $NF}' | tr -d ' '
```

A similar question "[Is there a command to see where a disk is mounted?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34718/is-there-a-command-to-see-where-a-disk-is-mounted)" uses the current disk's device node as input, and not an arbitrary file from the disk ...

Comment: You can do away with the final `tr` call by using `awk -F'% '...`

Comment: The equivalent on Windows is [`GetVolumePathName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getvolumepathnamew).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like

```
df -P FILE | awk 'NR==2{print $NF}'
```

or even

```
df -P FILE | awk 'END{print $NF}'
```

Since `awk` splits on whitespace(s) by default, you don't need to specify the `-F` and you also don't need to trim the whitespace with `tr`. Finally, by specifying the line number of interest (`NR==2`) you can also do away with `tail`.

Comment: the 2nd incantation worked out-of-the-box, while I had to change 2 to 3 in the first.  neat

Comment: @Gilles, thanks for the edit. One question, the second should work even without  `-P` right? In all cases, the very last field printed by `awk` should be the disk.

Comment: @Stu that's probably because I had not used the `-P` option that Gilles  just added.

Comment: @terdon Yes, indeed, the last field of the last line is the same without `-P`. Nonetheless I recommend always using `-P` when you're parsing the output of `df`, it's easier than checking that this particular use is safe.

Comment: nice. if you need to now the /dev entry for ${FILE} (for some reason) `mount | grep " on $(df -P ${FILE} | awk 'END{print $NF}') type" | awk '{print $1}'`

Comment: Not working correctly if  FILE is under a subvolume (in BTRFS filesystem).

Answer (score 24):

On GNU/Linux, if you have GNU `stat` from coreutils 8.6 or above, you could do:

```
stat -c %m -- "$file"
```

Otherwise:

```
mount_point_of() {
  f=$(readlink -e -- "$1") &&
    until mountpoint -q -- "$f"; do
      f=${f%/*}; f=${f:-/}
    done &&
    printf '%s\n' "$f"
}
```

Your approach is valid but assumes the mount point doesn't contain space, %, newline or other non-printable characters, you can simplify it slightly with newer versions of GNU `df` (8.21 or above):

```
df --output=target FILE | tail -n +2
```

Comment: My `df` doesn't recognize the `--output` option.

Comment: @JosephR. is it version 8.21 or above?

Comment: @terdon No it's version 8.13.

Comment: @JosephR. Stephane explains in his answer that this is a feature of GNU `df` >=8.21.

Comment: @terdon Sorry must have missed it while skimming.

Comment: @JosephR. I added that part after you mentioned it didn't work with yours.

Comment: Hi Stéphane, I know this is very old, but I can't find any reference to explain `f=${f:-/}` . I have run a few simple tests on cli and it seems that that bit is largely ineffectual. Do you might explaining briefly that particular bit of syntax ? The rest is very clear. Tx.

Comment: @Cbhihe, that's standard `${var:-default}` Bourne operator which expands to `default` if `$var` is empty. You'll find it documented in your shell's manual.

Comment: Passing `-m` instead of `-e` to `readlink` makes `mount_point_of` give a reasonably correct result for paths which don't exist. My use case is working out what mount a 'default' path would be on were it to exist.

Answer (score 14):

For Linux we have findmnt from util-linux exactly made for this

```
findmnt -n -o TARGET --target /path/to/FILE
```

Note that some kind of random mountpoint may be returned in case there are several bind mounts. Using `df` has the same problem.

Comment: Works correctly even with the files that are in subvolumes.

Answer (score 4):

Since `stat` returns a "Device" field, I was curious to see how the underlying `stat()` library call could be used to get this information programmatically in a POSIX compliant way.

This snippet of C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main (int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    struct stat info;
    stat(argv[1], &info);
    printf("min: %d maj: %d\n",
        minor(info.st_dev),
        major(info.st_dev)
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Will give the major and minor devices ID's for the device containing the file listed on the command line (`argv[1]`). Unfortunately, `major()` and `minor()` aren't POSIX, although the man page claims they are "present on many other systems    " besides GNU/linux.

You can then get a correspondence between the device major/minor number and the device node from, e.g., `/proc/diskstats`, and map that to mount points from `/proc/mounts`, aka. `/etc/mtab`.

So a command-line utility to do this would be pretty simple.

Comment: `/proc/diskstats` is only for block devices, you'll miss the NFS, proc, fuse... On Linux at least, different mountpoints can have the same maj+min

Comment: Did not know that, thx.  It also seems that `st_dev` may not provide a way to distinguish one NFS partition from another. Whoever actually wants to write this will have to take that into account ;)

Comment: +1 for being enough of a geek that you consider writing C code "simpler or more direct" than what the OP was doing :).

Answer (score 3):

Here's more C++ code if you want to do this from C++...

```
  #include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
  #include <sys/stat.h>

  /// returns true if the path is a mount point
  bool Stat::IsMount(const std::string& path)
  {

      if (path == "") return false;
      if (path == "/") return true;

      boost::filesystem::path path2(path);
      auto parent = path2.parent_path();

      struct stat sb_path;
      if (lstat(path.c_str(), &sb_path) == -1) return false; // path does not exist
      if (!S_ISDIR(sb_path.st_mode)) return false; // path is not a directory

      struct stat sb_parent;
      if (lstat(parent.string().c_str(), &sb_parent) == -1 ) return false; // parent does not exist

      if (sb_path.st_dev == sb_parent.st_dev) return false; // parent and child have same device id

      return true;

  }

  /// returns the path to the mount point that contains the path
  std::string Stat::MountPoint(const std::string& path0)
  {
      // first find the first "real" part of the path, because this file may not exist yet
      boost::filesystem::path path(path0);
      while(!boost::filesystem::exists(path) )
      {
          path = path.parent_path();
      }

      // then look for the mount point
      path = boost::filesystem::canonical(path);
      while(! IsMount(path.string()) )
      {
          path = path.parent_path();
      }

      return path.string();
  }
```

More links for programmatic ways

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453602/how-to-find-the-mountpoint-a-file-resides-on