# Is there a command to display mount points of contents of directories?

Tags: linux, mount

Is there a command, or maybe `ls` has a flag that also display the filesystem the contents of a directory is mounted on?

Comment: Quite likely a dupe of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90252/how-to-get-mount-point-of-filesystem-containing-given-file or of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34718/is-there-a-command-to-see-where-a-disk-is-mounted

Comment: `findmnt -no fstype -T directory`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lsblk`:

```
$ lsblk -o MOUNTPOINT,FSTYPE
/some/mounted/dir ext4
```