# Showing only "interesting" mount points / filtering non interesting types

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount

I used `mount` to show mounted drives, I don't want to see the not so interesting ones (i.e. non-physical). So I used to have a script `mnt` that did:

```
mount | grep -Ev 'type (proc|sysfs|tmpfs|devpts) '
```

under Ubuntu 8.04 and showed me `ext3` and `reiserfs` mount points only. That line is actually commented out and now I use (for Ubuntu 12.04):

```
mount | grep -Ev 'type (proc|sysfs|tmpfs|devpts|debugfs|rpc_pipefs|nfsd|securityfs|fusectl|devtmpfs) '
```

to only show my `ext4` and `zfs` partitions (I dropped using `reiserfs`).

Now I am preparing for Ubuntu 14.04 and the script has to be extended again (cgroup,pstore). Is there a better way to do this without having to extend the script? I am only interested in physical discs that are mounted and mounted network drives (`nfs`,`cifs`).

Comment: `alias mnt="mount | grep '^/dev'"` i use this to show the "devices" only.

Comment: Ah, the  good old times when this was just type `mount`.  I will never understand why this   command deserved the dirty bomb of the endless tmps, cgroups, pstores, debugfs, configfs and so on,  instead of use another commands   for such mounts or at least show only with some non-default option.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `-t` option for `mount` also works when displaying mount points and takes a comma separated list of filesystem types:

```
mount -t ext3,ext4,cifs,nfs,nfs4,zfs
```

I am not sure if that is a **better** solution. If you start using (e.g. `btrfs`) and forget to add that to the list you will not see it and maybe not miss it. I'd rather actively filter out any new "uninteresting" filesystem when they pop up, even though that list is getting long.

You can actively try to only `grep` the interesting mount points similar to what @Graeme proposed, but since you are interested in NFS/CIFS mounts as well (which don't start with `/`), you should do:

```
mount | grep -E --color=never  '^(/|[[:alnum:]\.-]*:/)'
```

( the `--color` is necessary to suppress coloring of the initial `/` on the lines found). As Graeme pointed out name based mounting of NFS shares should be allowed as well. The pattern either selects lines starting with a `/` or any combination of "a-zA-Z0-9." followed by `:/` (for NFS mounts).

Answer (score 47):

Do not use `mount`.

From `man mount`:

- The listing.

  - The listing mode is maintained for backward compatibility only.
  - For more robust and customizable output use [`findmnt`(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/findmnt.8.html), especially in your scripts.
  - Note that control characters in the mountpoint name are replaced with *?*.

Use `findmnt`, as the documentation suggests. Here are a few interesting options as described by `findmnt --help`:

- `-i` or `--invert`

  - invert the sense of matching
- `-R` or `--submounts`

  - print all submounts for the matching filesystems
- `-t` or `--types`*`list`*

  - limit the set of filesystems by FS types

Those are only a couple of the *many* filters you can apply on the commandline.

```
man findmnt
```

- EXAMPLES

  - `findmnt --fstab -t nfs`
  - Prints all NFS filesystems defined in `/etc/fstab`.
  - `findmnt --fstab /mnt/foo`
  - Prints all `/etc/fstab` filesystems where the mountpoint directory is `/mnt/foo`.  It also prints `--bind` mounts where `/mnt/foo` is a source.

You might use:

```
findmnt -it sysfs,cgroup,proc,devtmpfs,devpts,pstore,debugfs,hugetlbfs,mqueue,configfs
```

That *should* filter out all pseudo-filesystems, I believe.

Still, you can do the same with `mount`:

```
mount -t nosysfs,nodevtmpfs...
```

Possibly a better way might be to use one of either the following commands, which `findmnt --help` describes as noted:

- `findmnt -D` or `findmnt --df`

  - Imitate the output of [`df`(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/df.1.html). This option is equivalent to `-o SOURCE,FSTYPE,SIZE,USED,AVAIL,USE%,TARGET` but excludes all pseudo filesystems. Use `--all` to print all filesystems.

You can add list fields to the defaults with `findmnt -Do`*`+field,+field`*.... You can specify your own list of fields using only the file-systems `-D` would show by omitting the `+` like `findmnt -Do`*`field,field`*.

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea findmnt existed! To filter the filesystems, you could use `$(awk '/nodev/ { print $2 }' /proc/filesystems | paste -sd,)`

Comment: @deltab - if you're filtering by mount option you might as well do that with `findmnt`, too. But `nodev` is not necessarily an option restricted to non-pseudo filesystems. On the other hand, `findmnt -D` will get only those.

Comment: @insaner - that is more than enough, I assure you. I'm very flattered, thank you. But by the way, if `findmnt` surprised you then you might want top poke around a bit in the `util-linux` package - linux's libmount and friends have seen some pretty significant updates in the not too distant past. There's some pretty cool stuff in there. You might also like a look at the mount namespaces and shared mount trees.

Comment: @insaner - just as an example, for basically every case you might want to use a symlink, a `--bind` mount will do you better. Not only can you simply track and reverse it, you can also manage the entire indirection tree in fstab. And - w/ namespaces *(see `unshare` and `nsenter`)* you can present different views of the filesystem per process. It is completely acceptable to, for example, `--bind` mount `/dev/null` over an arbitrary file only for an abitrary process, to do so w/out root access if fstab defines the action, and to `findmnt --poll -N<pid>` the current mount state at your whim.

Comment: Added some more pseudo filesystems to ignore: `findmnt -it autofs,cgroup,cgroup2,configfs,debugfs,devtmpfs,devpts,fuse,fuse.gvfsd-fuse,fusectl,hugetlbfs,mqueue,proc,pstore,securityfs,squashfs,sysfs,tmpfs`

Answer (score 8):

How about:

```
mount | grep '^/[^/]'
```

Mount points relating to physical disks will always start with a `/` since the first field is the path to a device. `cifs` mounts will start with `//` so exclude lines with a second `/` to ignore them.

#### Update

I misread the question, I thought you wanted to *exclude* `cifs` and `nfs`. Try this instead:

```
 mount | grep -E '^[^ ]*[/:]'
```

Answer (score 8):

Late in the party, but

> I don't want to see the not so interesting ones (i.e. non-physical)

If by *physical*, you mean block devices attached to your PC, go with

```
$ lsblk
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sdb             8:16   0 238.5G  0 disk  
├─sdb1          8:17   0   100M  0 part  /boot
├─sdb2          8:18   0     1G  0 part  
├─sdb3          8:19   0    45G  0 part  /
└─sdb4          8:20   0 192.4G  0 part  
  └─ssdhomecr 254:0    0 192.4G  0 crypt /home
sdi             8:128  0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sdi1          8:129  0   801G  0 part  
│ └─test      254:2    0   801G  0 crypt /mnt/esata
└─sdi2          8:130  0 130.6G  0 part
```

I often use it with the `--fs/-f` switch (file system information)

```
$ lsblk -f 
NAME          FSTYPE      LABEL  UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sdb
├─sdb1        ext2        bootp  7cf4f62a-1111-4e2f-7536-4fc5ad38bd2c /boot
├─sdb2        swap        swapp  4aa6d4ae-11e7-4a35-8bf3-ab42313aca62
├─sdb3        ext4        sysp   b23338ad-5a4b54i54-a842-8164-a9a9a2a /
└─sdb4        crypto_LUKS        112c40c9-7fdd-4158-895c-5344d24c4a6d
  └─ssdhomecr ext4        homecr fc8a92cb-124f-4a0d-b88e-2055c06ffc3g /home
sdi
├─sdi1        crypto_LUKS        a7c9fg87-6962-43e3-b8c6-7605b181630e
│ └─test      ext2        esata1 124657dc-671a-4b7f-b8a7-b64d5341cabe /mnt/esata
└─sdi2        crypto_LUKS        1c5846bb-ce7e-4cbe-bb0a-b687758ea1dc
```

`lsblk` is part of [*util-linux*](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/). Obviously, it will not show *fuse* or network mounts.

Comment: The nice thing about `lsblk -f` is that unlike `mount` and `findmnt` will also show devices that are **not currently mounted**.

Answer (score 2):

A list of file system using a block device as backing storage can be obtained from `/proc/filesystems`. For example you could use it as follows:

```
mount -t "$(grep -v '^nodev' /proc/filesystems | cut -f2 | paste -s -d ,)"
```

Since you want both file systems backed by a block device and network file systems, it does not completely eliminate the need to maintain a list manually. But then you would only have to maintain a list of the network file systems you use.

I don't know how `/proc/filesystems` will treat those file systems which use multiple block devices for backing storage (i.e. file systems with RAID build into the file system). You might have to treat those special.

Comment: interesting approach! this still includes `fuseblk` though

Answer (score 2):

Combining several answers here (and expanding just a bit), here's what works best for me:

```
df -h | grep -P '^(F|/|[\w@.-]+:/)'
```

How I got here:

- `findmnt -D` is close, but it still includes a lot of `tmpfs` systems that I don't want to see.
- Of course, at the point at which you're *simulating* `df -h`, why not just run *that*?  The layout is a bit nicer, and the only thing you lose is the `FSTYPE` column, which I personally don't miss.  (For those that do, see below.)
- The regex in the accepted answer is just about perfect, but I tweaked it as follows:

  - I swapped `grep -E` for `grep -P`, which allows me to replace the more verbose `[:alnum:]` with the more compact `\w`.
  - It is not necessary to escape the `.` character when it's inside a character class.
  - A remote-mounted filesystem can contain an `@` if the user is included in the hostname (which I actually have an example of on my machine).
  - By adding `F` to the alternation, I retain the header line; a nicety only, but still handy.
- I did not personally need the `--color=never` (because I don't use an `alias`ed `grep`), but you could add that back in if you need it for your system.

If you really need to see the `FSTYPE` column, you can easily adapt this method to `findmnt` like so:

```
findmnt -D | grep -P '^(S|/|[\w@.-]+:/)'
```

Note that the only real difference on the `grep` side is that you have to swap `F` for `S`, because `df`'s header line starts with `Filesystem` while `findmnt`'s starts with `SOURCE`.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the `-v` switch.

Use:

`mount | grep -Ew 'ext4|ext3'`

This will show you only ext4 and ext3. If you want to view more filesystems, add them to the regex.

For example, to view ext3, ext4, cifs and nfs mounts, use:

`mount | grep -Ew 'ext4|ext3|cifs|nfs'`

Comment: The second one will also show `nfsd on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw)` on my system, the OP doesn't want that, that's why `type nfsd ` is filtered out.

Comment: @Anthon Thanks for pointing that out. I was trying to show the point of not using the `-v`. I have updated my answer. By the way, for what the OP is trying to achieve, your method (using `mount -t`) is the best.

Comment: I am not sure if `-t` is best myself. That I would forget to expand (if I start using `btrfs` or `xfs`) is unlikely, but forgetting `vfat` ( `iso9660`) for automounted (USB) physical drives is for real. I rather have a noticeable thing to filter than missing an (unseen) one I want.

Answer (score 0):

Best I use as an alias:

> df -Th| grep -Ev '(udev|tmpfs)''

sample output:

```
# df -Th| grep -Ev '(udev|tmpfs)'
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md3       ext4       39G  792M   36G   3% /
/dev/md2       ext4      487M   32M  426M   7% /boot
/dev/sda1      vfat      510M  152K  510M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/md5       ext4      7.2T  311M  6.8T   1% /var
```

but some of the answers above are very useful I might switch :

> findmnt --df
>
> lsblk -f