# listing directories under / that are not in the same mountpoint

Tags: linux, mount

If i have 8 directories under / , with 5 directories on different mountpoints then /

```
/dev/md/dsk/d0          49G    32G    17G    66%    /
/dev/md/dsk/d65         76G    77M    75G     1%    /u03
/dev/md/dsk/d64        345G    76G   266G    23%    /u02
/dev/md/dsk/d5          76G    77M    75G     1%    /u01
/dev/dsk/emcpower0g    591G   288G   297G    50%    /db
/dev/dsk/emcpower1g    591G   116G   469G    20%    /db2
```

Doing a ls -l

```
bash-3.2# pwd
/
bash-3.2# ls -l

drwxr-xr-x   3 root     sys          512 Jun 24  2014 boot
**drwxr-xr-x   5 root     root         512 Sep 16  2014 db
drwxr-xr-x   6 root     root         512 Sep 16  2014 db2
drwxr-xr-x  19 root     sys         5120 Jul 11 22:57 dev
drwxr-xr-x   2 root     sys          512 Jul 11 16:17 devices
drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root         512 Jun 25  2014 u01
drwxr-xr-x   4 root     root         512 Jul 11 17:08 u02
drwxr-xr-x   3 root     root         512 Sep  3  2014 u03
```

How do i filter/list to show

a) only those files and the other 3 directories (/boot, /dev, /devices..) that is created under / mountpoint

b) the 5 directories (e.g. /db, /db2, /u01..) that is under / but is mounted on different mointpoints

Answer (score 1):

For question b (directories on mount different from root):

```
{
  stat --printf='%d\n' /
  find / -mount -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%D%p\n'
} | awk -F/ 'NR==1{root=$1}; $2!=""&&$1!=root{print "/"$2}'
```

`stat` spits out the decimal device number of the root device. Then the `find` command lists the directories directly under `/`, together with the decimal device number. The output of both these commands is sent to `awk`. The `awk` prints out the directories if the device number does not equal the root device.  The `$2!=""&&` is there to filter out the actual root directory when answering the first question.

Change the last `!=` to `==` in the `awk` program to find directories part of the first question.

Comment: what about just adding -xdev to `find`?

Comment: ``-xdev`` does not descend into directories mounted on another device. It will, however, list the directories themselves, even if the contents of those directories is on another device.

Comment: Ahh, sorry. I misunderstood the original question.

Answer (score 1):

On a linux system you can use `findmnt`:

```sh
set ''
for r in /*
do  findmnt "$r"   || 
  ! set '' "$r$@"  &&
    ls "$r"
done
```

That command will do the `ls` for the *other* mounts, and all of the `/` root-mount filenames are available in `$@` when you're ready. So to list those you'd do:

```sh
ls "$@"
```